# How to change the entry point to something other than the default 'src/main.js' using Vite?

Tags: javascript, scala.js, vite

I want to point to a different location and file name and deviate from the Vite standard.

Let's say my `js` file is in `out/frontend/../../out.js`. I got it working when I rename it to `main.js` and copy it in the root of my project where `index.html` and `vite.config.js` live. But I would prefer to change the entry point somehow...

I tried this:

```
rollupInputOptions: {
  // or whatever your entry file is
  input: resolve(__dirname, 'out/frontend/my/path/out.js')
}
```

Did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

As of Vite 2, the entry file is specified in a `<script>` tag in `index.html`:

```html
<script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
```

You can change that file to the one you want:

```html
<script type="module" src="/out/frontend/my/path/out.js"></script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-custom-entry?file=index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use `resolve` from `path` module and add an alias in `vite.config.js` config to resolve paths, check.

```
import { resolve } from 'path'

module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': resolve(__dirname, '../out/'), // resolve path
    },
  },
  rollupInputOptions: {
    input: resolve(__dirname, '../out/entrypoint.js') // custom main
  }
}
```

- to import a module from resolved path use `'@'`, eg: `import { myModule } from '@/mymodule'`
- You will have to adjust the path of the new entrypoint in the `index.html` file.